# bit parsing program on c

Tags: c

I am trying to identify the logic that I can use for parsing the specific bit of the byte, I want to check if it is set or not and if it is then only move on to the specific line of code. 
I should be able to perform the AND or OR operation on binary value but again what if the location of the bit is 3rd or some other location then MSB and LSB, I will not be able to use the true or false condition in code, rather I will have to sue comparison of value with the AND or OR operation.

for example if AND operation is 00100000 then I will have to compare it with 00100000 and execute the condition statement.

Comment: `if (x & MASK) thenBitIsSet();`

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to do something along the lines of `if(condition(i, byte)) { doSomething(); }`, where `condition(i, byte)` is true if and only if the `byte` has a 1 at the i-th position. Is that correct?

Comment: What makes you think you can only test the MSB or LSB?

Comment: @Carey Gregory, I was not saying MSB or LSB can only be test, just wanted to give as an example.

Comment: @Alexander Weinert, yes your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like this:

First to note is the value 0 is false in C test, and any other value is considered true.

Then, to test if a certain bit is set or not, use tests like the following(one of the set of macros I made a few years ago)

`#define IS_SET(number, position) (number & (1 << position))`

then you can use it like this:

`if(IS_SET(15,2)){ }`. Note however, that the bit count starts from right most bit and moves towards left, counting from `0` for the right most bit.

The following is how the macro actually works(and note, this works for all integer types, 8 bit, 16 bit, 32 bit etc)
The number `15` in bitwise is `0x0F = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 00000 1111 1111` on a 32 bit machine.

Left shifting `1` 2 times, yeilds `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100`

ANDing the two numbers yeilds:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 &
------------------------------------------
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 (which is not 0, hence true)
------------------------------------------
```

This way you can test for any position in the bit sequence to be set or cleared.

Comment: Aniket , it will be great if you can explain little bit more the define statement. I am new learner of C prog.

Comment: @devnp I've explained how the macro actually works, in bitwise form

Comment: Don't forget to parenthesize `number` in the expansion of the macro.  You will not get the correct result if you use, for example, `IS_SET(max|min, 7)` because the expansion will not be correct.  Not dreadfully plausible as an example, but a valid concern nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks Aniket for explanation, somehow I was not able to see the portion of your post.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to test the N<sup>th</sup> bit of a byte (N = 0..7 for normal 8-bit bytes), you can use:

```
if (byte & (1 << N))
    ...Nth bit is set...
```

The test condition simply checks whether the expression is 0 (false) or non-zero (true).  You could make that explicit with:

```
if ((byte & (1 << N)) != 0)
    ...Nth bit is set...
```

You can set the N<sup>th</sup> bit with:

```
byte |= 1 << N;
```

You can reset (zero) the N<sup>th</sup> bit with:

```
byte &= ~(1 << N);
```

You can flip or toggle the N<sup>th</sup> bit with:

```
byte ^= (1 << N);
```

Although I've used the name `byte` throughout, you can do this with any bit of any of the integer types as long as your shift is in the correct range.